# Why is the non-persistent cookie not expired after closing the browser window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, cookies

From web I've learned that there are two types of cookies: Persistent Cookies and Non-Persistent Cookies. Non-Persistent Cookies are created if I don't specify the expiration time. I also learned that Non-Persistent Cookies are removed once the browser is closed, but in my case even though I closed the browser window, I can still navigate into my application without a successful login.

```
public ActionResult Index(Login userLogin)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Login Login = loginBusinessLayer.GetUserLogin(userLogin.UserId, userLogin.UserName);
        if (Login.UserPassword == userLogin.UserPassword)
        {
            Session["UserLogin"] = Login;
            User user = userBusinessLayer.GetUser(Login.UserId);
            Role role = roleBusinessLayer.Roles.Single(rle => rle.RoleId == user.RoleId);
            Session["Role"] = role;

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserLogin");
            cookie["LoginId"] = Convert.ToString(Login.UserId);
            cookie["RoleId"] = Convert.ToString(role.RoleId);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Success", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the set-cookie in the response from your Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: can you provide a document where i can learn how to do that?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/ shows you how to view `Response headers`. Once you are there, tick `Preserve log`. Then click `Clear` (next to the red button). Then load your page. Click on the first web request (scroll to the top, near Name). Under Headers there will be `Response headers`. Share with us any `set-cookie` entries there.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers continue to run in the background, even though all visible Windows are closed. For example Google Chrome on Windows need to be closed from the small notification icon in the task bar to really get shut down. If that is done, the session cookies are removed.

And for the record, that login method of yours contain a number of security flaws. I hope it just is an example. Use the built in libraries in asp.net: Asp.NET Identity and the Owin providers.

Comment: i removed the browser from task manager, still the cookie exists.